# Customizing the HTML for ValidationError in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I have a case where my client wants a more customized html Validation error on each field.  I figured this would be pretty straightforward, so this was my first approach

```
    public static MvcHtmlString MyValidationMessage(this HtmlHelper helper, string modelName, object htmlAttributes)
    {
        if (!helper.ViewData.ModelState.ContainsKey(modelName))
        {
            return new MvcHtmlString("");
        }

        TagBuilder builder = new TagBuilder("div");
        builder.AddCssClass("my-validation-message");
        builder.MergeAttributes(HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes));
        builder.InnerHtml += "<b>Custom</b>";
        builder.InnerHtml += helper.ValidationMessage(modelName);

        return new MvcHtmlString(builder.ToString());
    }
```

This really didn't work, because it doesn't integrate itself with the JQuery validation.  I decided to look at working more with the client side jquery validation framework, so I tried this...

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        debugger;
    }
});
```

And could't even get the debugger to even hit.

I am using MVC4

**NOTE:** I know this may be a duplicate of another question, but the answer was unsatisfactory.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you are trying to achieve?  Anything you put in $.validator.setDefaults(...) is ignored if you are using Microsoft unobtrusive validation script.

Comment: interesting, I'm just trying to create some custom html for the error messages.  Maybe an icon with some text next to it, but hard to do with the default <span> that overwrites the error message.

Answer (score 0):

The only other solution I can think of is to actually copy the source code from the .NET framework and suite it to my needs, I don't really see any other way.